# VBA Word - VBA can't find the custom style I made

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use a find and replace macro that finds a selection based on a custom style.

I tested what I'm doing with the built-in styles such as Heading 1 or Subtle Quote and had no problem running the find and replace. You would just simply replace the words `InlineAR` with `Heading 1` after `ActiveDocument.Styles ("`.

However, my issue is that when I made a custom style called 'InlineAR' and refer to that name in VBA (at `ActiveDocument.Styles ("InlineAR")`, my macro doesn't add the `"\textArabic"`snippet before any text styled with the InlineAR custom style.

Code at Issue:

```
Sub LaTeXStylingTextArabic()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("InlineAR")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = "\textArabic{^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you populate your selection?

Comment: Does it work if you try Find in the UI? And with Replace in the UI? If yes, try recording a macro then compare its code with what yours and see how they differ. Also note that Style names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @user1738964 Your code works for me. I made my own style, styled some text between normal, selected all of it, ran the code, and it properly inserted the tag. In addition to Cindy's comment about it being case sensitive, double check spelling and look for trailing spaces.